# Azure Batch and Connecting to Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, subnet, azure-batch

I have a C# console application running on a batch node that is trying to connect to a key vault. The pool, nodes and key vault are linked to the same subnet however when I try and get a secret the call timeouts - I think this maybe a network issue. Is there any network security permissions I need to set on the v-net or sub-net or node or pool that may resolve the timeout?

Or any step by steps instructions for getting a batch pool and nodes communicating on a subnet...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a virtual NIC on the VM hosting the C# app? They can have a Network Security Group (NSG), too, that can restrict access to network traffic. Another thing you should consider is adding a Service Principal to the VM and allowing access to KV. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-aad-auth. This won't solve your problem if it *IS* a network issue.

Comment: Michael - thanks for the advice. I have a AAD service principal which has access to the key vault. There is no firewall on the VNet however the Sub-Net is in a 'security group'. The batch node and key vault are in the same vnet.

Comment: Azure can use NSGs (Network Security Group) at the VNIC and Subnet level. You say the batch node and KV are in the same VNet, but are they in the same subnet? Can you dump the NSG on the subnet? In short, to keep things easy, make sure everything is in the same *subnet*